# Включить все заголовочные файлы

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то включить в `main.cpp` все возможные заголовочные файлы языка, чтобы каждый раз не думать, что подключать? Может есть специальный файл, который включает всё?

Comment: вы думаете, что их несколько штук?

Comment: @SKIP если бы я так думал, то просто прописал бы их вручную и не задавал вопрос

Comment: это невозможно)

Comment: Штатно такого не предусмотрено. Но вы всегда можете написать свой такой файл.

Comment: <bits/stdc++.h> для стандартных задач хватит)

Comment: @pavel у меня нет такого файла, где его скачать?

Comment: А потом код перенесут на другой компьютер и будут гадать, какие же библиотеки надо установить, чтобы появились какие-то там нужные заголовочные файлы, без которых код не собирается. Не надо так делать, пожалуйста

Comment: @pavel Покажите его в VC++ :)

Comment: Таскать с собой все инструменты мира, чтобы починить компьютер, точно также не совсем умно....

Answer (score 3):

Этого сделать нельзя. Никто не знает, что конкретно нужно программисту, а философия C++ всегда была такой: «ты не платишь за то, что не используешь». Учитывая то, что компиляция C++ кода это довольно ресурсоёмкий процесс, включение всех заголовков в основной (а какой считать основным, кстати?) файл привело бы к тому, что элементарный «Привет, мир!» компилировался бы слишком долго. При такой системе писать на этом языке было бы просто невозможно.